# C Programm of "ls -aln" but not working good

Tags: c, linux, unix, system

I've done a C program that does what the `ls -aln` command does, but I have a problem.

I expect this results :

```
drwxr-xr-x@  6 seven  staff   192 19 fév 18:58 .
drwxr-xr-x@  4 seven  staff   128  6 fév 00:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x@  7 seven  staff   224 17 fév 15:00 .idea
-rw-r--r--@  1 seven  staff   104  5 fév 17:37 CMakeLists.txt
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 seven  staff   352 19 fév 18:58 cmake-build-debug
-rw-r--r--@  1 seven  staff  2144 19 fév 18:58 main.c
```

but instead I'm having this:

```
d-----rwxr-xr-x  11  352     seven   staff   .
d-----rwxr-xr-x  6   192     seven   staff   ..
d-----rwxr-xr-x  6   192     seven   staff   cmake-build-debug
d-----rwxr-xr-x  6   192     seven   staff   CMakeLists.txt
d-----rwxr-xr-x  6   192     seven   staff   main.c
d-----rwxr-xr-x  6   192     seven   staff   .idea
```

Basically my number of links is not what I expected, size of files is not what I expected, the permissions are not all what I expected and then it says that all files are directory and add a "-" after that. I know it's probably caused by all the printf but I don't know how to fix this.

here is my code:

```
int main() {
    char* curr_dir = NULL;
    DIR* dir = NULL;
    struct dirent* entity = NULL;
    struct stat fileStat;
    struct passwd* pwd;
    struct group* gid;

    curr_dir = getenv("PWD");//current directory with PWD
    if (curr_dir==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: j'ai pas pris le repertoire courrant");
    }


    dir = opendir("/Users/seven/Desktop/Programmazione/TP");
    if(dir == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: j'ai pas pue ouvrir le repertoire");
    }

    while((entity = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        stat(entity->d_name, &fileStat);
        printf((S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");
        printf((S_ISLNK(fileStat.st_mode)) ? "l" : "-");
        printf((S_ISSOCK(fileStat.st_mode)) ? "s" : "-");
        printf((S_ISFIFO(fileStat.st_mode)) ? "p" : "-");
        printf((S_ISBLK(fileStat.st_mode)) ? "b" : "-");
        printf((S_ISCHR(fileStat.st_mode)) ? "c" : "-");
        printf((fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
        printf((fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
        printf((fileStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
        printf((fileStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
        printf((fileStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
        printf((fileStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
        printf((fileStat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
        printf((fileStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
        printf((fileStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
        printf("\t %u", fileStat.st_nlink);
        printf("\t %lld", fileStat.st_size);
        pwd = getpwuid(fileStat.st_uid);
        gid = getgrgid(fileStat.st_gid);
        if(pwd != NULL && gid != NULL ){
            printf("\t %s", pwd->pw_name);
            printf("\t %s", gid->gr_name);
        }
        printf("\t %s\n", entity->d_name);

    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

Comment: check the return value of stat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `entity->d_name` doesn't contain the full path of the file. All files you try to `stat` will be relative to the current working directory, not the one you passed to `opendir`. So some files will not exist and `stat` will silently fail (since you don't check for that).

Two possible solutions:

1. Change working directory to the one you use for the `opendir` call; Or
2. Append the directory and the `entity->d_name` (with path separator) and pass that appended name to `stat`.

And of course, add error checking for all calls.